# Drawbacks of embedding resources in binary as byte array?

Tags: ios, binary

To get around an iOS limitation with static libraries I'm embedding some binary resources (a few small images, primarily) in a static library as byte arrays.

Functionally - this works well.

My question is - what are the drawbacks of such an approach?

Specifically, if someone were to go overboard with this and embed tons of large resources in the binary - would this cause any problems?

Because I'm not 100% sure about how iOS loads binaries/etc I'm not sure if this data is all loaded into memory at the point the app is loaded, or is it kept in the DATA section and loaded from disk on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're generating the byte array. Is it PNG/JPEg data or raw pixels? The latter will be much larger in terms of storage space and memory than if you are storing JPEG/PNG data.

And the data in the byte array *is* always going to be in memory, and it will probably need to be copied again to actually load the image so you're using twice the memory as if you'd loaded it from a file.

Also you are missing out on some of the built-in behaviours that iOS has for managing images. For example if you load an image using [UIImage imagedNamed:@"foo.png"] the image is cached so it's quicker to load next time, and loading multiple copies doesn't result in duplicate memory usage, and the cache is automatically cleared if the memory runs low. If you load the image from data, you're missing out on those features.

The conventional approach is to supply a resources bundle along with your library and then load assets from the resources bundle using the NSBundle methods (you can load additional bundles and then use the pathForFile:... methods just like you do with the mainBundle).